# accessing service form another pod Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networking

I have two services running in my k8s.
I am trying to access my wallet service from my user service but my curl cmd just returns 504 gateway timeout.

here is my ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1$uri
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1/wallet
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wallet-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api/v1/user
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: accounts-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

this is the way I passed the env in my account service.

`http://wallet-service:3007`

and I log the URL when hitting my endpoint

`curl http://EXTERNAL_IP/api/v1/user/health/wallet`

every other non-related endpoint works.

Any help is appreciated

I am running Azure Kubernetes

Comment: What do your ingress controller's logs say?

Comment: Logging ingress or pod?

Comment: This is the logged url `http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/wallet/health`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two services running in my k8s.

1. Do you have an actual K8S service?

   ```yaml
   apiVerison: ...
   kind: Service
   ```

   - Check it with `kubectl get svc -A` and you should see your services there
2. Check to see that your pods are exposed to the services

   ```bash
   kubectl get endpoints -A
   ```
3. Are you running on a cloud provider (GCP, Azure, AWS, etc), if so check your security configuration as well (NSG for Azure, a security policy for AWS, etc)
4. Check inner communication :

   ```bash
   # Log into one of the pods 
   kubectl exec -n <namespace> <pod name> sh

   # Try to connect to the other service with the FQDN
   curl -sv <servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
   ```

#### Update:

- You commented that you are running on Azure, check the desired ports are opened under the NSG.
- Assuming that you are running AKS you need to find out the `MS_xxxx` resource and your NSG group will be located under this resource group, edit it and open the desired ports

---

You are trying to connect to http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/wallet/health - Where did you get the 3007 port?

Comment: I am running on Azure

Comment: port 3007 is the wallet service port.

Comment: You cant reach it from the outside unless you opened it in your NSG and you route to it. in your ingress you are routing to port 80

Comment: But that's to access the service externally. Services are in the same cluster so should be able to access with service name.

Comment: Like this. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster-services/

Comment: But that's to access the service externally. Services are in the same cluster so should be able to access with the service name. - *FROM WITHIN THE CLUSTER* or under the /api link not the way you try

Comment: curl -sv wallet-service.dev.svc.cluster.local
* Could not resolve host: wallet-service.dev.svc.cluster.local
* Closing connection 0

Comment: So you have problems with your services. do you have endpoints, I added the line in the answer

Comment: yes, this is the endpoint 10.244.0.16:3007

Comment: so your ingress should point to 3007 instead of 80

Comment: 80 is the service port. If I point it to 3007 that would conflict the service port.

Comment: Now it makes more sense you mapped 80:3007